# How to use a variable in other categories

Tags: flutter, dart, variables

I saved the value of 'result.address' received from the address api as a variable called final _resultAddress.

Assuming that you want to use this value in Text inside Child of Container, if you use Text(result.address), an error occurs. (undefiend name 'result.address)!

My question is simple. How can I use a variable in multiple places? (other methods, functions, etc.)

```
GestureDetector(
  onTap: ()async{
    await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (_) => KpostalView(
        callback: (Kpostal result) {
          final _resultAddress = result.address;
          print(_resultAddress);
        },
      ),
    ));
  },
    child: Container(
      height: 48.0,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.green,
        ),

      ),
      child: Text(_resultAddress),
    ),
  ),
```

I tried to name the variable final, const, static, but it didn't work.

Comment: please include your code where you defined the `result.address` and where it is not working.

Comment: Solved this as below.

String roadAddress = '';
 children: [
                                      Text('${this.roadAddress}'),
                                      Icon(Icons.search),
                                    ],

Answer (score 1, accepted):

declare it as global

```
final _resultAddress;
```

Then  use setState

```
callback: (Kpostal result) {
  setState(() {
   _resultAddress = result.address;
  });  
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare "_resultAddress" as a global variable and then Use it at any cate.